# Vue Typecript: declaring data with type

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

How can I achieve the following similar in Vue with Typescript?

`DocumentReference docRef = null`

```
export default Vue.extend({
    ...
    ...
    data: function(){
        return {
            docRef: null, //**here
        }
    },
})
```

Writing `docRef: null as DocumentReference` gives typescript error:

> conversion of null to type DocumentReference may be a mistake

I don't want to write `docRef: null as any` which suppresses any related error and warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To archive what you want, you must make the options passed to `Vue.extend` typed. For example:

```
interface VueExtendOptions {
  ...
  data: () => DocumentReference | null
}
const options: VueExtendOptions = {
  ...
  data: function(){
    return {
      docRef: null, //**here
    }
  }
}
export default Vue.extend(options)
```

Probably Vue has this interface done already, so I strongly recommend you to use it instead of creating your own.